Indexing / Slicing with Apache Spark to return a result to be used in a spark.sql query
The following simple spark sql query produces results
df = sql("""select FlagFileType from allprior""")


Without going into boring detail, I have coded a simple index to pull out the field "FlagFileType" as follows:
prykey = dfConfig['pky']


The problem is when I attempt to use the variable "prykey" to carry out the exact same query as follows:
df = sql("""select prykey from allprior""")

I get the following error:
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`prykey`' given input columns: [allprior.CountryFlag, allprior.CountryISO2, allprior.CountryISO3, allprior.CountryName, allprior.FlagFileName, allprior.FlagFileType, allprior.SalesRegion]; line 1 pos 7;
'Project ['prykey]

Can someone let me know where I'm getting the error when I use the variable?
I get a similar error if I try the following:
df = sql("""select allprior.prykey from allprior""")

But the following works fine:
df = sql("""select allprior.FlagFileType from allprior""")

When I apply the suggested solution to my full query as follows:
df = sql(f"""
select allprior.*, 'D' as Indicator
from allprior
left outer join maxversion on allprior.{prykey} = maxversion.{prykey}
where maxversion.{prykey} is null
union all
select maxversion.*, 'A' as Indicator
from allprior
right outer join maxversion on allprior.{prykey} = maxversion.{prykey}
where allprior.{prykey} is null
union all
select *, 'U'
from
(
    select *
    from maxversion
    except
    select *
    from allprior
) u
where.{prykey} in (select.{prykey} from allprior)
union all
select *, 'E'
from
(
    select * 
    from allprior
    intersect
    select * 
    from maxversion
) e
order by .{prykey}""")

I get the following error:
extraneous input '.' expecting {'(', '{', 'CALLED', 'CLONE', 'COLLECT', 'CONTAINS', 'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'COPY_OPTIONS', 'CREDENTIALS', 'DEEP', 'DEFINER', 'DELTA', 'DETERMINISTIC', 'ENCRYPTION', 'EXPECT', 'FAIL', 'FILES', 'FORMAT_OPTIONS', 'HISTORY', 'INCREMENTAL', 'INPUT',


It tries to find the prykey column in your table because it's just a string for spark, you just literally tell it select prykey. To make it work you need to format your string using the prykey variable. Assuming it's python:
df = sql(f"select {prykey} from allprior")


Hi @busfighter, thanks for reaching out. Your answer appears to fix my simple problem. However, I have updated the question with the full code. And although, your answer does actually work, there is something wrong with my syntax that is causing the following error extraneous input '.' expecting {'(', '{', 'CALLED', 'CLONE', 'COLLECT', 'CONTAINS', 

@Patterson you have several occasions of dots before {prykey} placeholders where it shouldn't be, like where.{prykey}, select.{prykey}, order by .{prykey}

@busfigher, yes you are correct. Once I made change it worked fine. Thank you very much mate.
